# Dynamically adding Text fields on C#2008 asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My C# web app requires the user to enter automobile information. The user can add information for one auto, or more (max 20).

My page has these text fields: Car Number, Car Make, Car Year, Mileage, VIN
I have a button that allows the user to "Add More Cars"
The idea is to allow the user to add more than one car.

When the user clicks "Add More Cars", how can I dynamically display the text boxes, and keep track of how many cars the user has added (in order to load them to an array and write to database)

Any other ideas that would make this objective easier? The control will only be used to enter data, not to view any records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using a placeholder and adding user controls.  It works quite nicely and is pretty modular.  Here is a quick example where I add a few controls based on a list.  You will notice I pass an object to my user control, allowing it to hide or show itself, display certain options etc based on permissions.  You could easily modify this code to add upon an event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comments.Count; i++)
            {
                controls.Comment commentCtrl = (controls.Comment)Page.LoadControl("~/userControls/Comment.ascx");
                commentCtrl.ID = "commentUserCtrl" + i;
                commentCtrl.setComment((myCommentObj)comments[i]);

                placeHolderComments.Controls.Add(commentCtrl);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following:

1. Add a placeholder or any other container control that will hold the text boxes.
2. At design time put one text box to that container.
3. Add run-time dynamically add a text box each time the user clicks "Add More Cars".
4. When the user posts the form retrieve child elements of the container control which are going to be the text boxes and loop through them.

Further more you could make a user control (ASCX file) of the text box for more control like handling events or adding a validator for each text box. You will then have to load the user control with LoadControl("YourTextBox.ascx") each time you add a new one to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListView to show a list of the cars entered.  Create an InsertItem template that has the template to insert a new car with, and on insert, have it update the DB by reloading the records, allowing them to insert.  You can wrap this with an UpdatePanel to make it asynchronous.

OR

If you want a pure client-side approach, use JavaScript to programmably create each entry, and then use a common scheme for creating the controls.  You can then check the form collection for posted values and extract all of the values, or stream the data back to teh server via web services from the client.

HTH.

Comment: I am guessing a Repeater control is not for data entry, correct?
ListView sounds like a better idea. Thanks

Comment: Nah, a repeater is a lighter version of a listbox, older and simpler. You can use it to show more textboxes alright, although it might not be the best approach. Try like this: add them to a div (server side) and then this div to place holder, so you keep things on their right places.

Comment: ListView is really nice to work with, is JavaScript/JQuery friendly, and handles the binding for you, which is why I like it. Repeater is a valid option...  I tend to prefer the ListView over the Repeater, but that isn't to say the Repeater isn't valid...